# Convert another php webpage to pdf and save in server on button click from current php page

Tags: php, pdf

I am using PHP4.4. And want to convert some other webpage to PDF and save it in server on button click from my current PHP page.

There are many options available but all supports PHP > 5 version.

I want some API where if I will pass webpage URL and click on a button from my current webpage, then it should convert that webpage to PDF and save in server.

Please suggest some free version API. Already tried many options like wkhtmltopdf, FPDF, PDFJs etc.but nothing works as I am using PHP 4.4.

Comment: If you have the necessary privileges on your server, you can install phantomJS. You can then use PHP to pass a URL to phantomJS, which will then do all the PDF conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do not have enough privileges to install anything in the server.

Comment: FPDF has older versions with php4